# How to plot subplots sharing the same datetime after applying sliding window?

Tags: datetime, matplotlib, time-series

I am having troubles making my subplots share the same x-axis(datetime) after performing sliding window to smoothen out the plot. I would like the datetime after windowing to share the same datetime as before windowing as illustrated in the picture below. I have also attached the codes to replicate the plots below.

[image]

```
from random import random
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Creating dummy datasets for illustration
date_example = []
for i in range (0, 365):
    date_example.append(datetime(2020, 9, 1)+ timedelta(days = i))
    
values = []
for _ in range (365):
    value = random()
    values.append(value)
    
date_example = pd.DataFrame(date_example)
values = pd.DataFrame(values)
example_set = pd.concat([date_example, values], axis =1, ignore_index=True)

# Creating sliding window on values dataset
wLen = 10     
values_windowed = [values[i*wLen : (i+1)*wLen] for i in range((len(values)+ wLen - 1)//wLen)]

values_windowed_mean = np.zeros((len(values_windowed)))
for i in range(0,len(values_windowed)):
    values_windowed_mean[i] = np.mean(values_windowed[i]) 

# Plotting the plots
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, figsize = (16,14))
ax[0].plot(date_example, values, label='Before Windowing')
ax[1].plot(np.linspace(0,70,num=len(values_windowed_mean), endpoint=True), values_windowed_mean, label='After Windowing')
ax[0].legend()
ax[1].legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What you are looking for is the `sharex` option**. When creating the subplots, you can specify `sharex=True` in order to link the x-axis of the two subplots. Also, you should use the same temporal values from the first (non-windowed) data set, with a downsampling.

Here is the last part of your code with the implementation, and the output below it.

```py
# Create two subplots with shared xaxis
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, figsize = (16,14), sharex=True)

# Plot two time series with same temporal vector
ax[0].plot(date_example, values, label='Before Windowing')
ax[1].plot(example_set[0].iloc[::wLen], values_windowed_mean, label='After Windowing')

# Cosmetics & show
ax[0].legend()
ax[1].legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: sharex subplots]

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the Pandas dataframe `example_set` why don't you use that:

```
# Plotting the plots
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, figsize = (16,14))

# change `0` in `example[0]` to the name of date column
# change `1` in `example[1]` to the name of the value column
ax[0].plot(example_set[0], example_set[1], label='Before Windowing')
ax[1].plot(example_set[0].iloc[::wLen], values_windowed_mean, label='After Windowing')
ax[0].legend()
ax[1].legend()
```

Output:

[image]